# I cannot get pyqt5 to run under anaconda python

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5, dllimport

I cannot get pyqt5 to run under anaconda python.  The following is an error message I get when I run a script shown below:

> Traceback (most recent call last
> File [full path to the python script], line 9, in <module>
> from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified module could not be
> found.

Here's the script that produced the error shown above:

```
import sys
print("Python version:  " + str(sys.version))
print("Version info.:  " + str(sys.version_info))
print("sys.hexversion:  " + str(sys.hexversion))

from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt5.pyqtconfig import Configuration

print("Qt version:", QT_VERSION_STR)
cfg = Configuration()
print("SIP version:", cfg.sip_version_str)
print("PyQt version:", cfg.pyqt_version_str)
```

I made the following attempts to fix the problem:

- I added "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" to the path variable for my User Win10 Environment Variables, after reading: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-%E2%80%9CImportError-DLL-load-failed-The-specified-module-could-not-be-found%E2%80%9D-in-Python-3    A comment suggested, "Just add the Python base DLL location to your path variable and restart the interpreter shell or IDLE."
- I verified that my "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" does include a python3.dll file

Here's my Python and PyQT5 installation info:

- I installed everything as administrator
- To install Anaconda: I ran Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86 64.exe, downloaded 2020-08-30 07:21 PM
- To install PyQt5: I was unable to run "conda install pyqt=3.8.6"   The Anaconda prompt said that the package was not available.
- So, instead, I ran:  conda install -c anaconda pyqt, as recommended by
  https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyqt
- Then I ran "conda list", which reports that I have installed: "qt 5.9.7   vc14h73c81de_0  [vc14]  anaconda"

But I still cannot run pyqt, because of the error shown at the top of this posting.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: _I added "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" to the path variable for my User Win10 Environment Variables_ The Conda docs discourage adding Anaconda to the path manually (see [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda)). _I was unable to run "conda install pyqt=3.8.6" The Anaconda prompt said that the package was not available._ Had you created a new environment for this?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that you're trying to install PyQt version 3.8.6? It seems to be quite old, do you know when it was released?

Comment: According to the return from "conda list", I installed PyQT5.9.7, which is the default PyQt installation version now.  I erred by trying to install PyQt3.8.6; I had wanted to install 5.8.6 to not be on the bleeding edge.  I had already added "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" to the path var for my User Win10 environ. variable; I also added that path to my PythonPath environ. variable.  If this leaves you perplexed too, can you suggest another forum where I could pose this question?  Lastly, thank you very much for your kind efforts.

Comment: _I erred by trying to install PyQt3.8.6; I had wanted to install 5.8.6 to not be on the bleeding edge._ Did you succeed in installing 5.8.6, then? It gives the same error? _I had already added "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" to the path var for my User Win10 environ. variable_ You had added it "manually" ?

Comment: You asked if I succeeded in installing 5.8.6. The installation routine "conda install -c anaconda pyqt" completed w/o errors, and when I ran "conda list" to find out which packages were installed, one of the installed packages listed was "qt 5.9.7 vc14h73c81de_0 [vc14] anaconda".  Lastly, yes I am still getting the same error.

Comment: _You asked if I succeeded in installing 5.8.6. The installation routine "conda install -c anaconda pyqt" completed w/o errors, and when I ran "conda list" to find out which packages were installed, one of the installed packages listed was "qt 5.9.7 vc14h73c81de_0 [vc14] anaconda"._ Is that not the expected behaviour, since `conda install -c anaconda pyqt` should install the latest compatible version? In any case, 5.9.7 is the version of qt, not pyqt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with PyQt - after upgrading to spyder 5.2.2 neither anaconda nor spyder would open at all - no splash screen etc or anything - it didn't even try to start the programs. Trying to start from the prompt, "anaconda-navigator" and "sypder" both returned:

```
(base) C:\Users\Geography Chair>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 233, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 41, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 44, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 188, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR as PYQT_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
SystemError: initialization of QtCore failed without raising an exception

(base) C:\Users\Geography Chair>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QEvent, QObject, Qt  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
  File "C:\Users\Geography Chair\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 188, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR as PYQT_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
SystemError: initialization of QtCore failed without raising an exception
```

After a fair bit of messing around (conda install -c anaconda pyqt, conda install -c conda-forge pyqt, installs with specific versions...) I finally tried just updating pyqt (conda update pyqt). It worked. This is what it returned, if it helps anyone:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pyqt-5.9.2                 |   py38hd77b12b_6         3.3 MB
    sip-4.19.13                |   py38hd77b12b_0         261 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         3.6 MB

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  ply-3.11-py38_0
  python_abi-3.8-2_cp38

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    conda-forge::ca-certificates-2022.9.2~ --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2022.10.11-haa95532_0 None
  pyqt                  anaconda::pyqt-5.9.2-py38ha925a31_4 --> pkgs/main::pyqt-5.9.2-py38hd77b12b_6 None

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi            conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2022.9.24~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2022.9.24-py38haa95532_0 None
  conda              conda-forge::conda-22.9.0-py38haa244f~ --> pkgs/main::conda-22.9.0-py38haa95532_0 None
  openssl            conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1q-h8ffe710_0 --> pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1q-h2bbff1b_0 None

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  sip                                  6.6.2-py38hd77b12b_0 --> 4.19.13-py38hd77b12b_0 None
```